# sending multiple sms android

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, mms

I am attempting to send multiple sms in android via the newly enforced sms intent method (as opposed to the old sms_permission method).  The goal is to enable the user to send the same message to multiple recipients without the recipients being able to see or respond to each others conversation.  This varies from a standard mms method where the recipients can read and respond to each others messages.

The new intent method does not actually send the sms, but rather opens the standard android messenger application and populates the text field with the text inputted within my application, and all the user has to do is press the send button within the messenger app.  Is there a way to do this multiple times in a sort of queue where the user can click the send button for each specified recipient, or is there an easier way to send an MMS where recipients cannot see or respond to each other?

Comment: You can request SMS permissions for your app. See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en

Comment: @DavidWasser that is correct.  However, sms permission exceptions are only granted to apps that need it for their core functionality; this is a feature of the app but not core functionality.

Comment: Have you tried to submit your app and request these permissions?

Comment: Otherwise you will need to send your SMS in a loop, starting the SMS app each time and waiting until it is done and then sending the next one.

Comment: @DavidWasser The permission is not an option unfortunately.  Would you monitor the SMS app for when the user presses the send button, and then generate another SMS for them to send (and continue until all messages are sent)?